# CLR Stored Procedure returns SqlDataReader but the method type is void

Tags: c#, sqlclr

This is will return datareader but the method type is void. How to get the SqlDataReader value from the method to modify it in business layer?

```cs
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void GetStates() // Method
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            StringBuilder StateQuery = new StringBuilder();
            StateQuery.Append("SELECT OID,Name ");
            StateQuery.Append("FROM ");
            StateQuery.Append("State");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(StateQuery.ToString(), connection);
            SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(command); //Return
       }
   }
```

Comment: Change the method's return type and return the reader?

Comment: CLR Stored Procedure should have return type void

Comment: It looks like the `SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend` "sends" the data to the client -- [CLR Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx), thus you don't "return" the data, the client needs to have an open pipe to receive.

Comment: Yes i know that. My question here is how to open/get the data from the return value from SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get data using ExecuteAndSend().  In order to get data back to an application, you need to open a SqlConnection, create a SqlCommand using that SqlConnection, and call SqlCommand.ExecuteReader or SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar.

On the other hand, the question is ambiguous. The reason to create a CLR Stored Procedure is to execute this CLR as a Stored Procedure. In that sense, it will not send any data to the app layer as it is being called by T-SQL, not by the app layer.

That being said, since the goal here is to simply execute the `SELECT OID, Name FROM State` query, there is absolutely no reason to do this via SQLCLR. Just do a regular SqlCommand in the app layer to either run that simple query OR exec a regular T-SQL proc that encapsulates that query. In either case you will get a result set so you call SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() to get those results. This operation is a very straight-forward SELECT from a DB and should not be over-complicated with SQLCLR.

Side notes:

- The return type of a CLR Stored Procedure does not *need* to be void. Procedures, T-SQL and CLR, can return a type of INT / Int32.
- SqlContext.Pipe is mainly used for sending information (queries to execute, results to display as part of a result set, or messages [that display in the Messages tab in SSMS]).

Comment: If I want to return a DataReader/DataTable. Then how to do?

Comment: @Kumar, return the DataReader/DataTable to where, exactly?

Comment: I want to call this CLR SP from Business Layer. When my state SP returns a Datatble/DataReader i will bind the result

Comment: @Kumar, that usage makes no sense. Why do you need a CLR proc if calling from the Business Layer? Is this just a test and the real code is more complicated or do you really just want to exec that simple `SELECT OID,Name FROM State` query?

Comment: I am just want to execute this select OID,Name from state

Comment: @Kumar, I just added a paragraph to my answer addressing this. There is no need at all for SQLCLR. This is a very basic query that should be handled in the standard manner.

Comment: I have few more complex procedures which will return complex data. If I use SQLCLR how to return DataTable/DataReader

Comment: @Kumar, the issue is not the data that is being returned but the logic inside the proc. You shouldn't be using SQLCLR unless you can't accomplish your goal with T-SQL, or if doing it in T-SQL would be too slow. Regardless, a Stored Proc, whether T-SQL or CLR, _cannot_ return a DataReader; it can only return OUTPUT params and Result Sets. So if you need .Net functionality, then you can create a CLR proc but it still needs to return a Result Set, and then you would EXEC that proc via `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.